# pyqt - combobox item enabling/disabling line_edit item based on state

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to have a combobox enable/disable a line_edit item based on the current option selected in the combobox/state of the combobox.

This is the closest I've gotten so far

```
self.combobox_widget.activated.connect(self.line_edit_widget.setDisabled)
```

However, this only works if the first option in the combo box is the one that needs to have the line_edit enabled and it also disables the line_edit for every other option.

I'd like to get it so that I could have multiple options disable the line_edit and have multiple options enable the line_edit.

I've been looking up class info and method info from http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html
but haven't been able to get anything else to work.

I know the basic idea is to connect to the combobox, listen for signals generated by changing the states, and then setting the line_edit to enabled or disabled based off of the values associated with the signal that was sent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create another function, and connect the combobox to it. Don't use `activated` though, use `currentIndexChanged`, as you don't need to do anything if the `index` isn't changed.

```
def comboBoxIndexChanged(index):
  #Do something based on the index
  if somethingBasedOnTheIndex:
    self.line_edit_widget.setEnabled(true)
  else:
    self.line_edit_widget.setEnabled(false)
```

The reason it's behaving as you have it is because the `activated` signal is sending the `QComboBox` index to the function. Which is then being cast to `true` or `false`. Python is then casting the `0` to `false` (enabling the `QLineEdit`), and every other index is being `true`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of the index being casted to a bool!  Working now with your suggested changes.